# string.Join() doesn't work as expected

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, linq

[image]Feeling a bit stupid here. Maybe I'm missing something, but why doesn't the following simple call work as expected:

```
String.Join(" ", "CSharp".ToCharArray())
```

You'd expect it to return "C S h a r p", but interestingly it returns "CSharp". Moreover, the following call returns correct results:

```
String.Join(" ", "CSharp".ToCharArray().ToList())
```

Comment: Just ran this on my machine and it works properly. Inside a console, MessageBox and the output window.

Comment: In a message box as well as in QuickWatch window.

Comment: @Nope! First one is also returnung `C S h a r p`, for me in console window.

Comment: try checking your code again as the first one also works as expected.

Comment: @Everyone: I added a screenshot.

Comment: The close-voters chose "This question doesn't appear to be about programming..."... ironic.

Comment: @dotNET - For me, its coming correct even in Quick watch.

Comment: Which version of the framework are you using?

Comment: Looks like I made a little mistake in tagging. This occurs for me in VB.NET, not C#. The framework is 4.0 and I'm using VS2013 Express for Desktop.

Comment: i get your results in vb.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following returns true in C#

```
var result = String.Join(" ", "CSharp".ToCharArray()) == String.Join(" ", "CSharp".ToCharArray().ToList());
```

This return false in vb.net

```
Dim result = String.Join(" ", "CSharp".ToCharArray()) = String.Join(" ", "CSharp".ToCharArray().ToList())
```

---

It seems `String.Join(" ", "CSharp".ToCharArray())` in vb.net is using

```
Shared Function Join ( separator As String, ParamArray value As String() )
```

ie its converting `"CSharp".ToCharArray()` to 1 single string

---

IL for VB.net `String.Join(" ", "CSharp".ToCharArray())`

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       " "
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0007:  newarr      System.String
IL_000C:  stloc.1     // VB$t_array$S0
IL_000D:  ldloc.1     // VB$t_array$S0
IL_000E:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000F:  ldstr       "CSharp"
IL_0014:  callvirt    System.String.ToCharArray
IL_0019:  newobj      System.String..ctor
IL_001E:  nop         
IL_001F:  stelem.ref  
IL_0020:  nop         
IL_0021:  ldloc.1     // VB$t_array$S0
IL_0022:  call        System.String.Join
IL_0027:  stloc.0     // result
```

IL for C# `String.Join(" ", "CSharp".ToCharArray())`

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       " "
IL_0006:  ldstr       "CSharp"
IL_000B:  callvirt    System.String.ToCharArray
IL_0010:  call        System.String.Join
IL_0015:  stloc.0     // result
```

Comment: Thanks for testing and confirming, but should this be an *answer* then?

Comment: Looks like you're right. VB.NET is implicitly converting char array to string. I just created a dummy method with one string parameter and passed it a char array, and it happily accepted it. Strange to say the least; especially when I have set `Option Strict ON`.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Basic is getting caught up on which parameter to actually use.

In VB a `Char()` is practically the same as a `String`. Take for instance this code:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Test(s As String)
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim foo As Char() = "CSharp".ToCharArray()
        Dim foo2 As String = "CSharp"

        Test(foo)
        Test(foo2)

        Dim equal As Boolean = foo = foo2
        Console.WriteLine(equal) 
    End Sub
End Module
```

Visual Basic allows a `Char()` to be passed into a method as a string. This is throwing off your `String.Join` because it is using the wrong parameter. I would attempt to use `List(Of T)` instead of `Char()`.

Remember, there really isn't a `String.Join( String, Char() )` overload. There is `Join(Of T)`, however, I can't seem to get the compiler to let me actually set `T` on it.

Comment: String.Join(" ", {"VBDOTNET"}.ToCharArray().ToList)